# Flutter in_app_purchase '_enablePendingPurchases': enablePendingPurchases() must be called before calling startConnection

Tags: flutter, dart, in-app-purchase

I am using the simple code below

```
bool available = await InAppPurchaseConnection.instance.isAvailable();
```

however it is returning the error

> E/flutter (14525): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:in_app_purchase/src/billing_client_wrappers/billing_client_wrapper.dart': Failed assertion: line 101 pos 12: '_enablePendingPurchases': enablePendingPurchases() must be called before calling startConnection

I was wondering if anyone knew a reason for this error and if so what should i fo about it, Happy to have any suggestions - thanks.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The documentation is very thin on this and should actually be more clear. You need include the line below in main() for it to work.

```
void main() {
  ///Include this in main() so purchases are enabled
  InAppPurchaseConnection.enablePendingPurchases();

  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Comment: I agree with you, the dependency is awesome, but the documentation is very poor. Glad I came across this.

Comment: @Martins completely agree with you there

Comment: I'm trying to integrate in-app-purchase in my app. Please give me some reference links that you followed to integrate this plugin. I'm getting products list as empty though my app is published. There is an article regarding this plugin on medium, but i don't have subscription on medium. Please help me.

Comment: @KPradeepKumarReddy https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase

Answer (score 1):

I could not import InAppPurchaseConnection to try the accepted solution, and fixed this issue with the following:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:in_app_purchase_android/in_app_purchase_android.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  // Inform the plugin that this app supports pending purchases on Android.
  // An error will occur on Android if you access the plugin `instance`
  // without this call.
  if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android) {
    InAppPurchaseAndroidPlatformAddition.enablePendingPurchases();
  }
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```